# Como hago que prompt funcione? Pone que no esta definido (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, function

Quiero usar

```
var Chat = prompt("")
```

Pero me pone que `prompt` no esta definido, yo leí que las funciones deben ir a la izquierda de la columna

Comment: Quieres hacer funcionar esto desde la consola con nodejs?

Comment: Si, es nodejs, aun no se diferenciarlo del javascript

Comment: Prompt no existe propiamente, deberás ir a la doc y buscar como leer datos desde la consola

Comment: Ah, entonces prompt es de javascript y yo estoy usando nodejs?

Comment: Nodejs es javascript pero propmt solo existe dentro del navegador y tú estás usando la consola

Comment: Ah, ya entendi gracias

Comment: Una vez lo intenté y no recuerdo si lo logré a la perfección. Para eso hay que cambiar momentáneamente el `process.stdin`, y el `process.stdout`. Desde mi punto de vista, la consola del _Node_ al ejecutarla directamente es como si estuvieras en modo _prompt_ todo el tiempo, si lo usas así en vez de ejecutar un archivo `.js` ya no necesitarías un _prompt_, directamente llamas a una función con los parámetros que quieras y es como si le estuvieras hablando a la consola.

Answer (score 1):

El prototipo de nuestra función `prompt` será el siguiente:

```
function prompt(mensaje,callback_prompt){ /*...*/ }
```

Le pasamos como parámetro dos valores:

1. El mensaje de inicio, o la pregunta que le queremos hacer al usuario.
2. El `callback_prompt` es la función que procesa la entrada del usuario.

La función `callback_prompt` al llamarla podemos ponerle otro nombre, por ejemplo `comprobar_respuesta`.

```
function comprobar_respuesta(x,callback_mostrar){
    /* Hacemos las comprobaciones necesarias */
}
```

Para usar el `prompt` se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
prompt("¿Cuánto es 5+7?",comprobar_respuesta)
```

Nota: Para esta pregunta en específico, en caso de acertar la respuesta muestra el mensaje *Correcto*, en caso contrario muestra *Incorrecto*. Los posibles resultados pueden ser *0b1100* o *0x0C*, ya que acepta cualquier número equivalente a *doce*.

Antes de llamar a la función `prompt` se espera un mínimo tiempo para que el usuario suelte la tecla <kbd>Entrar</kbd>.

```
prompt(/* parámetros */)
// Aquí ya se desapretó la tecla Entrar.
```

Para esperar *el tiempo mínimo (10 milisegundos)*, el segundo parámetro del `setTimeout` no se especifica, y solo se pasa la función.

```
setTimeout( function(){/**/} )
```

Entonces la función `prompt` queda algo como lo siguiente:

```
function prompt(mensaje,callback_prompt){
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Se hacen las operaciones necesarias.
    })
}
```

Lo primero que hace la función `prompt` es guardar el `process.stdin` en una variable (la llamaré `stdin_copia`) y luego reemplazar el `stdin` por una función propia:

```
var stdin_copia = process.stdin._events.data
```

Se guarda y al final el `prompt` se recuperarla:

```
process.stdin._events.data = stdin_copia
```

Luego de que el usuario respondió la pregunta, también ocurre que hay que *esperar milisegundos*, porque es la segunda entrada del usuario, luego de haber ingresado la respuesta y haber soltado <kbd>Entrar</kbd>.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    process.stdout.write("> ")
    process.stdin._events.data = stdin_copia
})
```

Se muestra *un signo mayor y un espacio (`>`)* . Son símbolos que indican que el sistema espera la entrada del usuario (esto hay que hacerlo si se está entrando directamente al *Node*). Además, vuelve a usarse el `stdin` original, porque ya no se necesita usar el `prompt`.

```
> prompt("¿Cuánto es 5+7? ",comprobar_respuesta)
undefined
> ¿Cuánto es 5+7? 014 Correcto. // Lo ingresa en octal.
> ▧
```

Aquí hay una serie de acciones:

1. Se llama a la función `prompt`. El usuario escribe `comprobar_respuesta)` y luego presiona y suelta la tecla <kbd>Entrar</kbd>.
2. Para poder preguntar, antes tiene que mostrar el resultado de llamar a la función, que en este caso es `undefined`.
3. Muestra `undefined`. Esto es obligatorio, no se puede ocultar porque forma parte del *stdout*.
4. Se muestra la pregunta. Puede escribirse la respuesta justo al lado (a la derecha).
5. Espera a que el usuario ingrese la respuesta. El usuario escribe *0o14*, luego presiona y suelta la tecla <kbd>Entrar</kbd>. Espera que procese y muestre el resultado para luego volver al `stdin` original.
6. Muestra el resultado, en este caso es *Correcto*. Aunque el usuario soltó <kbd>Entrar</kbd>, esto se muestra a la derecha en vez de abajo, porque aún tenemos nuestro propio `stdin`.
7. Se *muestra el signo mayor con el espacio (`>`)*. Por último se cambia el `stdin` por la función original, que estaba referenciada en la variable `stdin_copia`.

Lo siguiente asigna nuestra función al `stdin`. El parámetro `x` es la tecla del teclado que recibe, y es un *Buffer*, es decir, parecido a un array, pero muestra los elementos en hexadecimal:

```
process.stdin._events.data = function(x){ /* procesar */ }
```

Como siempre se ingresa una tecla solamente, el buffer tiene *1* de longitud. Se va armando un string con cada tecla ingresada:

```
console.log(x)  
if( "\x0d"==String(x) ){ // <Buffer 0d> es tecla 'Entrar'
    callback_prompt(respuesta)
    // ...
}
```

Para completar la respuesta a la pregunta *5+7*, que es *12*, se debe ingresar tres teclas, la <kbd>1</kbd>, la <kbd>2</kbd> y por último se hace una comprobación para ver si se tocó la tecla <kbd>Entrar</kbd>, que en hexadecimal es `\x0d` (también significa un salto de línea).

```
respuesta+=x
process.stdout.write(x)
```

Mientras va llenándose la *respuesta*, con `stdout.write` se muestra en la consola cada letra que se va ingresando. Al tocar <kbd>Entrar</kbd> ya está armada la `respuesta`, y se pasa como parámetro al *callback*, para poder comprobar si es correcta.

Código en *Node.js*:

```
function prompt(mensaje,callback_prompt){
    var stdin_copia = process.stdin._events.data
    setTimeout(function(){
        process.stdout.write(mensaje)
        var respuesta=""
        var stdin_copia = process.stdin._events.data
        process.stdin._events.data = function(x){
            // console.log(x) // tecla que se pulsa hexadecimal
            if( "\x0d"==String(x) ){ // <Buffer 0d> es tecla 'Entrar'
                callback_prompt(respuesta)
                setTimeout(function(){
                    process.stdout.write("> ")
                    process.stdin._events.data = stdin_copia
                })
            }
            respuesta+=x
            process.stdout.write(x)
        }
    })
}
function comprobar_respuesta(x){
    if( eval(x) == 12 ){
        console.log(" Correcto.")
    }else{
        console.log(" Incorrecto.")
    }
}
prompt("¿Cuánto es 5+7? ",comprobar_respuesta)
```